# ngServe error when running a quickstart app

Tags: angular

when trying to run a cloned angular quickstart app from terminal i see the following error.

> Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.
>
> Please take the following steps to avoid issues: "npm install
>   --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"
>
> Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be
>   determined. The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
>
> Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli
>   and typescript in devDependencies, then delete node_modules and
>   package-lock.json (if you have one) and run npm install again.

Comment: Now that you've seen the error, read it. It tells you what's wrong, what to check, what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If i am you. i would run `npm cache clean` to make sure you remove all the dependencies then install what it says followed by the `npm install`